# Bug when edit values of nested list that generated using multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

Welcome All

I try to make list using python named **mylist** with 3 element each element contain other list contain 2 element like these

```
[[None,None]]*3
```

When try to edit first nested list items in my list by set `mylist[0][0] = 1` and `mylist[0][1] = 2`
Then try to print **mylist** This is output : `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]` It edit all list items.

However when create it manually like `mylist = [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]` then try to make my edit edition done correctly.

First Case Code :

```
mylist = [[None,None]]*3

mylist[0][0] = 1
mylist[0][1] = 2

print(mylist)
```

First Case Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Second Case Code :

```
mylist = [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]

mylist[0][0] = 1
mylist[0][1] = 2

print(mylist)
```

Second Case Output:

```
[[1, 2], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

Comment: List multiplication does not create copies of the list - it repeats a reference to the same list multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because multiplying a list doesn't actually create copies of itself like how a string does. For the effect you are looking for, you can use a module called NumPy, use numpy_r for that.

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.array([[None, None]] * 3])
print(mylist)
```

Output will be:

```
 [[[None None]
 [None None]
 [None None]]]
```

Or:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.r_[[[None, None]] * 3]
print(mylist)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[None None]
 [None None]
 [None None]]
```

The second one doesn't have an extra dimension, if you didn't figure that out.

If you don't know much about NumPy then click [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/), you can check [here](https://numpy.org/install/) to install NumPy.
And if you want to access for eg. the first item, the you use mylist[0][0] but in NumPy arrays, you use mylist[0, 0].
And @Guimoute has the answer in the comments for doing it using standard python without modules.

Edit: I had written some code wrong, I have corrected it. Don't get more frustrated for the code not working, there was just an error.

Comment: You want to use `[[None, None] for _ in range(3)]`, not numpy.

Comment: @Guimoute Still, NumPy arrays are better in every single circumstance, so NumPy solution is going to be better.